# How to obtain the BFD architecture specification for the current platform?

Tags: gcc, gnu-toolchain, objcopy

I've embedded a text file in a C program using the following method: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967

```
a.out:prog.c file.text
    objcopy --input binary --output elf64-x86-64 --binary-architecture i386 file.text file.o
    gcc prog.c file.o
```

**objcopy** requires to specify the target with the "--output" option.

How can I set "--output" in Makefile so objcopy will use the user's architecture ?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is, of course equivalent to asking *"How do I learn the correct architecture specification from the command line?"*, but the answer is not clear to me.

Comment: I tried to use 'uname' but it doesn't give me the solution.

Comment: Yeah. I tried that too. And I looked at `file` and `ar` and `nm`. The only thought I had was a custom `magic` file for `file`, but I don't know enough to begin assembling such a thing.

Comment: It would help if you told us what OS you have. Different systems have different syntax for asking about architecture.

Comment: Since you speak of a "user" here: Do ***please*** not introduce this objcopy hack into production or release it into the wild. It is a beautiful hack, but just meant as a hack: Showing what technology can do. In *any* practical use, just load the file at runtime or use simple sed/awk/perl/whatever magic to convert it into a C file.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly: You are not trying to emulate the `-b` capability of the GCC ld, are you? In more verbose terms: The GCC ld can actually load a number of binary formats, see [the documentation](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_2.html). If that's what you want to achieve, something like:

```
 gcc prog.c -Wl,-b -Wl,binary file.o
```

might save you the whole objcopy call.

While I'm not able to find documentation on the issue, the output of `objdump -i` seems to be sorted by preference, so

```
 `objdump -i | head -n 2 | tail -n 1`
```

should expand to the usual target architecture. Stating again: I have no documentation on this behaviour, so better don't rely blindly on it.

Comment: Thanks for this quick BFD target one-liner!

Comment: When I try this in a test program, `gcc` moans at me ```$ gcc use-binblob.c -Wl,-b -Wl,binary binblob -lc
/usr/bin/ld: .../libc.so:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of _binary__lib_x86_64_linux_gnu_libc_so_start; .../libc.so:(.data+0x0): first defined here
...
/usr/bin/ld: .../Scrt1.o: in function _start:
(.text+0x16): undefined reference to __libc_csu_fini
...
/usr/bin/ld: use-binblob.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to putchar
/usr/bin/ld: a.out: hidden symbol __TMC_END__ isn't defined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: (various errors related to being unable to link in libc; it seems that the `-Wl,b` "transfers" to the entire output object. I suspect this can be solved with linker mapfiles (to make sure it only is applied to the binary blob file and nothing else); I haven't figured out how yet though,