# Meaning of Endianess in "objcopy -O ..."? Does binary data get mangled?

Tags: binutils, objcopy

after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271231/476371) I immediately thought to myself:

Why exactly do I have to tell whether it's Little or Big Endian? Does it mean that instead of simply copying my binary input data, `objcopy` mangles the data in some way, depending on the Endianess chosen?

The example at hand was:

```
objcopy -I binary -O elf(32|64)-(big|little) binblob binblob.o
```

If this is **truly binary data**, `objcopy` shouldn't have to care, right? Whatever *reads* the data later on would have to, but `objcopy` shouldn't have to ...

Does `objcopy` mangle the data based on the bitness and Endianess given by the `-O` option?

Comment: Normally you don't have to specify the endianness, as that's either stored in the object file or deduced from the host.

Comment: And with binary data you *really* have to care about endianness. Think about the (16-bit) value `0xf0b2`. On a big-endian system that is stored as the two bytes `0xf0` and `0xb2` (in that order), but on a little-endian system the bytes are stored in the order `0xb2` followed by `0xf0`. If you use the wrong endianness you could get the value `0xb2f0` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if I don't give `-B` how would it deduce it? After all none of `elf32-big`, `elf32-little`, `elf64-big`, `elf64-little` are architecture-specific ... but there isn't something like an `elf-binary` _bfdname_.

Comment: What is the format of `binblob.o`? How was it created? If it's an ELF object file, the byte-order will be specified in the ELF header. As will the word size (32 or 64 bits).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no I don't have to care about Endianess. In my case the binary data is going to be a string. You make the assumption that the binary data is already in the form of - say - integers or other C types. And that's exactly the question I have: does `objcopy` also make such assumption and if so, how does it mangle the data? Last but not least it would be a whole lot easier if I wouldn't have to give a specific _bdfname_ at all, since the data I want to store is not to be interpreted as some C type (and if it were, I'd take care of conversion _in code_ ... I promise ;)).